# Akka remoting won't start

Tags: akka, akka-remoting

I’m new to Akka and I’m working through Jason Goodwin’s well written book Learning Akka. His examples use activator though, and since activator is gone I’ve recreated his examples from chapter 2 without activator. The problem is that my code (without activator) doesn't start remoting.

I've also downloaded [his code](https://github.com/jasongoodwin/learning-akka.git) and it works after doing `sbt clean publishLocal` and `sbt run`.  However if I just copy his src/ directory and his build.sbt to another project I get the same problem.  Remoting doesn't start.

My client also cannot connect to a running database (his code with activator).

This code is all based on Akka 2.3.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which exercise are you running? Could we see some logs? Though, any reason to use a 3 years old outdated repository? You have a tone of starters in the lightbend site https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=akka

Comment: I used the akka-quickstart-java.  No starters for Akka remoting, however.

Comment: Maybe checking out one of the guides would help? This one for example: https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-sample-cluster-java/